# Rename all models in rails application without losing data. Database used is mySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application, all models to be renamed with out losing data. The database in use is mySQl. Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the tables names from mysql console using following syntax:

```
RENAME TABLE old_table TO new_table
```

If you want to keep the old table names but a new model class name  use `set_table_name` method:

Lets say your model was called Book and new you renamed it to NewBook. If you want to continue to use the books table :

```
class NewBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'books'
end
```

To rename the model use the IDE like RubyMine. They have very good code refractoring tools.